# JavaScript for display current year plus next year on June 1

Tags: javascript

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with what I'm missing with the following JavaScript (I am converting a giant site from PHP to Javascript because the organization has switched to a new CMS).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("year1").innerHTML = getYearOffset("0000-06-01", -1);
// plus 1 year
document.getElementById("year2").innerHTML = getYearOffset("0000-06-01", 1);
</script>
```

Then in-line code:

```
<span id="year1"></span>-<span id="year2"></span>
```

I want this to display current year - next year on and after June 1.

The original functioning PHP was:

```
  <?php if (date('m') > 06) {
    echo date('Y');
    } else {
    echo date('Y')-1; }
    echo "-";
    if (date('m') > 06) {
    echo date('y')+1;
    } else { 
    echo date('y'); }
     ?>
```

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. I have been struggling with this bit of JavaScript, probably from exhaustion!

Comment: In PHP code, it is checking the month of `date`. Do you have that value on your client side, because looks like you are getting the yearoffset from hardcoded value?

Comment: @PM Yes, I'm a luddite with JS. Thanks

Comment: @PM yes, correct. Someone else coded the PHP, I am tasked with migration/conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with JavaScript only as well but there is more simpler alternative way to do it using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) a very popular lib for *Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times in JavaScript.*

To get exact next year from a specific date this is the method : `moment().add(1, 'years');`

Checkout below working code:

```js
let date = moment().year() + "-06-01";
let y1 = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(y1);
let y2 = moment(y1).add(1, 'years').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(y2);

document.getElementById("year1").innerHTML = y1;
// plus 1 year
document.getElementById("year2").innerHTML = y2;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
<span id="year1"></span> - <span id="year2"></span>
```

Comment: There's also [this library of pure date functions](https://date-fns.org/). It's lighter weight than moment. I've preferred it lately

Comment: @VicJordan Sorry for my ignorance but how can I get this code to display in the HTML? I've been trying my usual tricks but am not familiar with let commands. Thanks

Comment: @beingbecoming please check my updated answer. You can display in HTML now.

Comment: @VicJordan Thanks. Sorry I'm such a beginner with JavaScript. This displays dates in the HTML like: 0000-06-01 - 0001-06-01 but I want it to display today "2018-2019" and on June 1 of 2019 to display 2019-2020. I will keep working with your code. Thanks.

Comment: @beingbecoming yes. Is this you wanted, right? `0000` is just a dummy year which you mentioned in your question. You can enter year of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, it might have been a dummy year created by a dummy. (me) I wanted to pull the current year (2018) and was obviously way off the mark!

Comment: @beingbecoming Checkout now. Done!

Comment: @VicJordan Thank you so much! After 12+ hours coding today my brain was simply mush and you save me a huge headache. It is not exactly what i was trying to explain but I can fix it to get what I wanted. Answer accepted and I truly appreciate your patient help.

Comment: @beingbecoming You are welcome. Happy to help you. Please upvote as well if not done yet!

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions did exactly what I wanted so I began again from scratch and made something new (that actually works!). Part of the problem is that I was not entirely clear (both in my mind and in the formation of my question on here) what I needed/wanted the script to do.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 
today = mm;

if (today >= 07){
var theDate = new Date();
var curr_year = theDate.getFullYear();    
var next_year = theDate.getFullYear()+1;
}

else if (today < 07){
var theDate = new Date();
var curr_year = theDate.getFullYear()-1;      
var next_year = theDate.getFullYear();  
}
</script>
```

and

```
<script>document.write(curr_year + "–" +  next_year);</script>
```

If the month is prior to June, the script should write "last year" - "current year."
If the month is June or later, the script should write "current year" - "next year."

So much more complicated than a fairly simple command in PHP!